# Is matplotlib really only available for power pc OS X?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The latest matplotlib [download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.0/) only shows OS X 10.3 download options for mac. Wikipedia [claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Panther) OS X 10.3 is Power PC only.  It seems strange to me that there is no option for downloading matplotlib for Intel based macs.  Is this correct?

Comment: Try it. The 10.3 may be just an indicator of the minimum supported version of OS X. (See also http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#install-osx-binaries which indicates that at 0.99 there was a 10.5 build; if you look you'll see it's only since 1.0 that that's gone.)

Comment: I don't have my mac easily available :(  I'm creating installation instructions for someone else.

Comment: I just use macports, which works perfectly and usually has very recent versions of matplotlib, numpy, and alike.

Comment: As a note, 1) `matplotlib` is now hosted on github, and 2) definitly works on intel macs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found an Intel mac.  Seems to work.  No complaints from the installer at least.

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib installation is a tricky beast and althought I have it installed in my python2.6 environment I cannot replicated that success (yet) under a new python2.7 (using virtualenv). So Far:

1. using the "10.3" dmg as suggested above appeared to install properly but throws an unknown architecture error when trying to plot.
2. using easy_install fails for me on an unknow architechure error during the freetype2 part of the install.
3. Downloading the tarball and compiling from source throws the same error.  I will eventually tweek the config settings to get **MY** install to work but I'm not sure that that will help anyone else (sorry Dejas).

Freetype2 and libpng are common culprits for install problems. You could try to google your way through others efforts.  Having installed it on a number of osx systems, tarball source install seems to be the most reliable route.  If you are not up on what easy_install is (from your question) then you might want to seriously consider one of the [Enthougth Python installs](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php%20Enthought%20Python).

**Update:** One machine allowed the source and/or easy_install.  I finally just rsync'ed my way to a working condition on my second machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `easy_install matplotlib`

Comment: easy_install is a method to install python libraries. Running that command in the OS X terminal (possibly as root) will cause matplotlib to be compiled and installed. You may also need the developer tools installed.